# Actionmailer css adding to the whole app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm trying to style my actionmailer mail view by doing the following:

I have an `email.css.scss` file with:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

a {
    color: #23527c;
    a:hover {
        color: #1C70BB;
    }
}
```

in my `assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( email.css )
```

in my `send_email.html.erb`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'email' %>
```

But now when I go into my app all the links `a` are in this color but I haven't imported the `email.css.scss` in the `application.scss` file.

How can I just put the `email.css.scss` file to just be read in this specific email view?

Also, I do `rake assets:precompile` if this has something to do with it.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I followed this article on how to send emails using rails and bootstrap:

http://stefan.haflidason.com/sending-emails-using-rails-and-bootstrap/

It uses two gems for this:

```
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'premailer-rails'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have to style mailers inline (in the actual mailer template), and once you do so, the mailer styles won't have an effect on the rest of your app. You won't be able to use SCSS/SASS there either.

The easiest way to style mail templates is to use a  tag at the top of the mailer template.

Just because you've precompiled your mailer assets along with the rest of your app doesn't mean that a user's email program will be able to load them. When it comes to email, inline/tables is king. It feels kind of 1995-ish, but that's the way it is.

Comment: oh that reminds me that I read this article http://stefan.haflidason.com/sending-emails-using-rails-and-bootstrap/ on how to send the emails with styling using two gems `nokogiri` and `premailer-rails` which does what your telling me. I'll add this to the question.